# List Workflows Not Working on Site Created From Template

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, site-template

I have a Site (say "Site A") with a List workflow. I saved the site as a template. When I create another site (say "Site B") from the template, the workflow is there but it does not work. It also doesn't work to add a new Workflow to Site B. It's as though a setting prevents using Workflows.
Additional details:

- Site A is a site with Server Publishing activated; this means I had to set "SaveAsTemplate" to True in Designer in order to even save it as a Template
- I've tested Site B with "SaveAsTemplate" set to both true and false; makes no difference - the workflows do not work

Any help?!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be aware of the publishing site or site with enabled publishing features can't be saved as a template .

- If you try to Navigate to site setting you will not find `save site as template` option,
- Also, if you tried to use SharePoint Designer , or direct link `/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx` you will get

[image]

So I am pretty sure , you tried to use PowerShell as a workaround , that will be saved your site as template correctly but unfortunately, you will face more issue like "adding new workflow issue "! because it's not supported method.

**Note :** if you tried to deactivate publishing feature to can save site as a template this also not considered a supported method.

My suggestion, Try to create a team site and migrate your data and functionality from old one , in this case, you can save your site as a template that should work properly .